# Sinister: Left slides to malicious, but how?

Tags: etymology

How did "sinister" migrate from the Latin for "left" to English for "evil"?

Comment: How did *gauche* migrate from the French for "left" to *tactless*. How did the Anglo-Saxon word *lyft*, meaning *weak* or *foolish* turn into the English word for *left*?

Comment: It's just culture. 'Left' is considered in a negative light in most cultures (for whatever reason), and so by semantic shift gets associated with other negative things. I've heard that, because people tend to be right handed, it is easier to defend with a sword to the left, and so you put your enemy on the left. That is a bit of an extended folk-explanation. It's probably simpler, that left is just considered 'weaker' in general, and words change towards similar things.

Comment: @Mitch: I'm inclined to believe the *right-hand/sword* explanation (I reckon that's the underlying reason we Brits drive on the left). I've also heard that in some [primitive] cultures the left hand is reserved for "toilet duty", so it would be disrespectful to offer it for a potentially contaminated handshake. *That* one seems like a bit of extended folk-explanation to me.

Comment: This question may have an answer here.  See the answer by SAH http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209021/is-denigrate-a-racist-word

Answer (score 2):

From [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=sinister&searchmode=none):

> The Latin word was used in augury in the sense of "unlucky, unfavorable" (omens, especially bird flights, seen on the left hand were regarded as portending misfortune), and thus sinister acquired a sense of "harmful, unfavorable, adverse." This was from Greek influence, reflecting the early Greek practice of facing north when observing omens. In genuine Roman auspices, the augurs faced south and left was favorable. Thus sinister also retained a secondary sense in Latin of "favorable, auspicious, fortunate, lucky."